# Getting OG tags from Forbes article

Tags: node.js, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to get OG tags from forbes.com site articles using [openGraphScraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper), but as forbes allways load first the home page, and then redirects to the article in a few seconds, I am getting allways the home page OG data. There should be a way to solve this, because facebook loads the correct OG data.
Any help will be really appreciated.